# Android: data collection and privacy policy

Tags: android, google-play, privacy

My app uses `Admob` ads and `Google Analytics`. Do these collect any [sensitive information](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security/additional-requirements/) for which prominent disclosure needs to be provided?

Is it necessary to show an age gate at app start to make sure the user is at least 13 years old?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about privacy policies / terms and conditions / legal issues instead of directly about programming or coding.

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at both to determine what kind of data they collect from your users.

AdMob and Google Analytics collects data that can serve behavioral marketing (remarketing) and you're required to disclose this to users and provide them with information how to opt-out of Google's remarketing:

- https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2753860?hl=en&ref_topic=2745287
- https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just doing some quick googling, I found [this page](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/targeting) that gives some information on admob and COPPA requirements. I want to say that I've never seen an app that uses admob give me some coppa notice, and google analytics would generally only be data you collect from users on who is using your app (general, like age, gender, location, etc) and how. Unless you are specifically targeting ages <13, imo you should be fine.